# Photoshop Layer Order after Created

Tags: javascript, photoshop, jsx

I write script like below code just for New Layer in Photoshop.
But I would not like to my new layer order to TOP of all Layers.

Please help me for avoid new layer to jump to top of all previous layers.

```
var create_NewLayer = function ()
{
    var newLyer = activeDocument.artLayers.add();
}
create_NewLayer();
```

I improved a bit, but still need help, result same as previous.

```
var create_NewLayer = function ()
{
    try
    {
        if  ( app.documents.length )
        {
            var doc = app.activeDocument;
            var currentDoc = doc.activeLayer;

            // New Layer Create
            var layers = doc.artLayers;
            var newLayer = layers.add();

            // Move Before Last Active Layer
            layers.move(getLayerIndex(currentDoc), PsElementPlacement.PLACEBEFORE);
        }
    }
    catch (e)
    {

    }
}
create_NewLayer();
```

Comment: What does "not top" mean? The bottom? Middle? What have you tried? Have you even [referenced the script documentation](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-javascript-ref-2015.pdf)?

Comment: Maybe I can't explain what is my issue is.

Comment: And I am still working on it.

Answer (score 3):

I tried this, and eventually found a line of code that would successfully move a new layer before the previous layer:

```
var docRef =  app.activeDocument 
docRef.artLayers[0].move(docRef.artLayers[docRef.artLayers.length-1], ElementPlacement.PLACEBEFORE);
```

I think there must be a way to do a for loop to iterate through the layers and keep moving your new layer all the way to the bottom.

`docRef.artLayers.length` returns the number of artLayers you have.

You may need to use Layer sets to accomplish what you're trying to do.  I found the following code [on this page](http://cssdk.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/sdk/1.5/docs/WebHelp/app_notes/ps_doc_model.htm):

```
// Get a reference to the first layer in the document
var layerRef:Layer = app.activeDocument.layers.index(0);

// Create a new LayerSet, by default at the top of the document
var newLayerSetRef:Layer = app.activeDocument.layerSets.add();

// Move the new layer set to after the previously first layer
newLayerSetRef.move(layerRef, ElementPlacement.PLACEAFTER);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I will try it later when I take a time for it. Now I use another scripts and it works good. Thanks for your valuable time. Respect!